# Windows node bootstrap using chef

Tags: chef-infra, winrm

I am new to chef, i am trying to bootstrap a node using chef through winrm transport mechanism. I am getting error that is can't connect to the node.
Can someone help me out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To best help you, please edit your question to include the specific error messages you are getting, which commands you are running, and what version of ChefDK you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have also used winrm for bootstrapping windows node `knife bootstrap windows winrm 127.0.0.1 -p 2222 --winrm-user vagrant --winrm-password 'vagrant' --node-name windows` this worked for me.

Comment: if you are facing issue with this, let me know